# replace string inside the table sql

Tags: mysql, concatenation

i got some problem about replacing string inside the mysql table with some requirement. You can see my current table :

```
+----+------------------------+  
| id | data                   |  
+----+------------------------+  
|  1 | [text1]mytext1[/text1] |
|    | [text2]mytext2[/text2] |
|    | [text3]mytext3[/text3] |
|    | [text4]mytext4[/text4] |
+----+------------------------+
```

then i need to change `[text3]mytext3[/text3]` to `[text3]mytext5[/text3]`

and the problem is :

1. how can i find the string [textX] and [/textX] ?
2. how can i replace the content between the [textX] and [/textX] ?

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Use LIKE to find the hits, then REPLACE To make the change:

```
update mytable set
data = replace(data, 'mytext3', 'mytext5')
where data like '[text%]mytext3[/text%]'
```

Comment: yeah,that's worked...but,if i wanna take the [text3]...[/text3] as the requirement of "LIKE" (not "mytext3" as the object of changing) what's your suggestion about that?

Comment: I don't understand. You said it worked. What else is there to it?